# tell me the service to verify the number via sms

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I need to enable SMS verification for the site. That is, a person enters a phone number, he receives a code via SMS, a window opens on the site where you need to enter the code. Suggest some simple service, preferably without php

Comment: You will need some kind of SMS Provider and write your own small Backendserver implementing the API. There are several SMS APIs on the web you can subscribe to. Prices can vary.

Answer (score 1):

One service that, as far as I know, is the most popular one is https://www.twilio.com, but there are also some alternatives.

I can suggest two approaches.

1. Using send SMS feature

- Create an endpoint for starting SMS verification. This endpoint will create some temporary code and save it to some storage(database, redis, smth else). And then send SMS to the user using Twilio API.
- Create an endpoint for code verification, where user should send a code from SMS, you will verify that code is matched with saved in storage.
- Also I suggest restricting the time when the user can resend code.

2. Twillio Verify API: https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api

- I have not tried this, and I'm not sure how it works
- I see one issue with this approach, if you want to migrate to another SMS service, this service probably will not support such a feature, and you will need to reimplement SMS verification.